# Removing trailing 0 xml Ireport

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm currently having trouble when producing an *iReport*, when I run the report it's giving me a weight of 29000.0kg but I require just 29000kg. I've tried different formats but I understand it might need changing in XML.

If anyone could point me in the right direction or assist me in changing this please comments

Currently this is the XML code that is against fields:

```xml
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{EquipmentTareWeightKg} +"kg"]]></textFieldExpression>
```

Any ideas on how to include this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured this out, it doesn't require hardcoding but merely changed in the properties window within ireport designer, however if you see below, you change the pattern value to remove decimal places:

```
</textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{EquipmentLengthMm} /1000]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
    <textField pattern="###0" isBlankWhenNull="true">
        <reportElement x="399" y="0" width="32" height="20"/>
    <textElement>
    <font size="12"/>
</textElement>
```